# armv7s error while Archive in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linker command failed with exit code 1 xcode4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12534334/linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-xcode4-5)

I am getting following error while i am archive my app for app store

ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv7s slice: /Users/***************/l******/*****ppCircle.a for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

i tried to remove armv7s from my target then some new error start occuring.how i can resolve it

Comment: This might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976516/not-able-to-build-my-project-on-xcode-4-2

Comment: What is your deployment target and minimum OS

Comment: Universal App and ios 5.0

Answer (score 0):

The problem is : you are using a library call : ****ppCircle.a and this library was not compiled for armv7s.
Only two solutions :

1) If you have the library source code, you can try to compile it for armv7 AND armv7s

2) Instead of compiling your project with armv7s, use armv7 only (this can be changedin the project build settings)