# Getting error of armv7s and armv7 while archiving for release

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am getting error when archiving (for release)

```
ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

ld: entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture armv7s
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which version of xcode you using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429494/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-armv7  check out this

Comment: I have followed that, but still the same error, if i change archive mode from release to debug, there is no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally after a lot of tries I got the answer, the problem was related to private path, as there should be a public path for 3rd party library.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your answer, i am also eager to know about the error.

Comment: Can you please be a little bit more specific, as I have the same problem and cannot find a solution.

Comment: what do yo mean public/private path ? i have the same error and im using few 3rd libs

Comment: Private/public path is, the folder path(where folder is saved) of 3rd party libs, save folder into your project and change path from Library Search Paths.

Comment: what? can you explain a bit more? encountering the same issue.

Comment: Remove all paths from library search path ,copy your 3rd party libraries into your project and add path of libraries again.

Answer (score 7):

My Issue was this:
Somehow my "main.m" got removed from "Compiler Source" in my Project Settings/Target.
Adding it back, SOLVED it.

Answer (score 0):

check in your build settings is like in this picture, if its not then update your code setting like this, this pic is take from my project which is working perfectly[image]

Comment: same setting, almost try every thing :(

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution for your problem, you don't have main.m method, create it like this,

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

Comment: @PrachiRajput http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976516/not-able-to-build-my-project-on-xcode-4-2 Try this..

Comment: I couldn't understand why it is working for archiving in debug mode.

Comment: Solved my problem. I, too, already had a main.m but it was not in (Project Overview -> Targets -> Build Phases -> Compile sources). Readded and everything works fine again!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing the iOS Development Target to the min version of the Xcode supported resolved this issue, see image:
[image]
It was 5.0, which is far lower than the Xcode 13's min supported version, which is 9.0.
Changing it to **iOS 9.0** worked well.