# xcode 8 archiver entry point (_main) undefined. for architecture arm64

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

> Ld
>   /Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RoadApp.build/Release-iphoneos/RoadApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RoadApp
>   normal arm64
>       cd /Users/macos/Desktop/RoadAppIOS
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.1
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -L/Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/WYPopoverController
>   -L/Users/macos/Desktop/RoadAppIOS/RoadApp -F/Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/macos/Desktop/RoadAppIOS/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks -F/Users/macos/Desktop/RoadAppIOS/Pods/GoogleMaps/Maps/Frameworks -F/Users/macos/Desktop/RoadAppIOS/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks -F/Users/macos/Desktop/RoadAppIOS/RoadApp -filelist /Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RoadApp.build/Release-iphoneos/RoadApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RoadApp.LinkFileList
>   -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.1 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RoadApp.build/Release-iphoneos/RoadApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RoadApp_lto.o
>   -fembed-bitcode -Xlinker -bitcode_verify -Xlinker -bitcode_hide_symbols -Xlinker -bitcode_symbol_map -Xlinker /Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -ObjC -all_load -ObjC -lWYPopoverController -lc++ -lz -framework Accelerate -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework
>   CoreText -framework GLKit -framework GoogleMaps -framework
>   GoogleMapsBase -framework GoogleMapsCore -framework GooglePlaces
>   -framework ImageIO -framework OpenGLES -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration -framework UIKit -lsqlite3 -lPods-RoadApp -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RoadApp.build/Release-iphoneos/RoadApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RoadApp_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/macos/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/RoadApp-dxgwdfigzxouoygvxpckcaxymfbd/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/RoadApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/RoadApp.build/Release-iphoneos/RoadApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RoadApp

Hi. I searching for 1 day but can find solution, can anyone help?

EDIT: check all solution on this page but not work
[Getting error of armv7s and armv7 while archiving for release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725704/getting-error-of-armv7s-and-armv7-while-archiving-for-release)

Answer (score 1):

make sure you have this tag on the top of the appdelegate file, and you didn't accidentally deleted it

`@UIApplicationMain`