# Error when creating Archive

Tags: ios, live-streaming, ijkplayer

i m implementing rtmp streaming player and its work fine on device, 
but when i create archive of project, error occurred,

I am using this framwork:      **IJKMediaFramework** and its working good, but not able to create Archive

[image]

Comment: It looks like your IJKMediaFramework binary is missing armv7 architecture.

Comment: @yes.. its not look like.. its missing, but how do i solve it.

Comment: Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21725704/getting-error-of-armv7s-and-armv7-while-archiving-for-release

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems some files are missing!

I face same issue, I found  IJKMediaFramework.framework.zip at https://pan.baidu.com/share/link?shareid=729122436&uk=2134088328

Its working fine for me...

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have included the Xcode project into your own project as well.

Check the IJKFFMoviePlayerController group in Xcode & ensure all the files from GIT are included there. In my case, the files listed above were missing. Adding them manually (by dragging them into the group) fixed it.

Make sure that yasm is installed in your environment before building IJKMediaFramework with FFMPEG and replace following string in confing/module.sh

export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --disable-protocol=async"

with

export COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS="$COMMON_FF_CFG_FLAGS --enable-protocol=async"

Comment: i dont have module.sh file, are you using cordova?